# Hard Boiled Eggs: does meat or dairy flavor penetrate shell?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, eggs

I tried searching this but got a lot of results about cooking three eggs in one pot checking for blood spots at cetera.

Suppose that you hard boil some eggs in a pot that is normally used to cook meat. Or, you hard boil the eggs in a pot that is normally used to cook dairy.

Does the dairy or meat "flavor" penetrate the shell of the egg and a render the edible part dairy or meat?  Or does it remain parve?